# Google Cloud Build Windows Builder Error "unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation"

Tags: containers, google-cloud-build, docker-for-windows

I am trying to implement automatic deployments for my Windows Kubernetes container app. I'm following instructions from Google's [windows-builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/windows-builder).

The Cloud Build trigger fails upon running the docker build command with this error "unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication". Here is a screenshot of the logs:
[image: Cloud Build Logs]

As the error message recommended, I tried following the steps from the [advanced auth documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication). Unfortunately, this didn't do the trick. Below I'll summarize the important steps I took while following that documentation.

1. I already had Docker Desktop and Google SDK installed on my computer. Throughout this entire process Docker Desktop was on the Windows mode, instead of the default Linux.
2. Ran the command `whoami` in command prompt to get my domain\username for the next step. My laptop doesn't have a domain so the domain part was just laptop-[laptop-number].
3. Ran the command `net localgroup docker-users [domain]\[username] /add` in admin command prompt. I received the "error" of "The specified account name is already a member of the group". I took this as a good problem and restarted my computer.
4. Decided to follow the [gcloud credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud-helper) authentication method for the rest of the steps.
5. Created a new service account, made it GCP project owner, and created a key for it.
6. With the newly created SA and the key downloaded to my laptop, I authenticated into Google SDK with this SDK command `gcloud auth activate-service-account [sa-account] --key-file=[sa-key-path]`
7. Ran the command `gcloud auth configure-docker` from the SDK. In response, I was told that it was "Adding credentials for all GCR repositories". I understood this as a success message
8. Updated the Cloud Build trigger to use the new SA that I created and authorized.
9. I re-ran the job only to come back to the same error

I'm not sure where to go from here. Is there anything that I need to do specifically for windows container? Am I following the steps from the advanced auth documentation correctly? Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the `gcr.io/XXXX`, XXXX reference the current project or another one?

Comment: The gcr.io/XXXX from the error logs references my onbuild container.  XXXX is the same project that Cloud Build is in. Everything is in one GCP project. Also, It may be worth noting that my app's foundational container utilizes the public Windows OS container "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019"